Audio project converting TSH-4 headset to 3.5 mm audio jack

I've been trying to connect this TSH4 headset to a 3.5 mm audio jack. The headset has kind of a weird setup, with Mono audio + and - being the top pins (I don't know which is which, but the polarity doesn't matter anyways), and the bottom being for the throat mic/laryngophone.)
However, a 3.5 mm (stereo) audio jack only has one ground, and does not feature a plus and a minus for audio, and I am very new to audio projects.
Would it be possible to wire the + and - of the ear cups to either L/R and GND, and then turn on MONO audio? Then on top of that I'd like to be able to use the microphone, but that just uses the V and the GND pin right?
If anyone could recommend to me what to do, I'd be very happy. I've seen several videos on this idea, but they all use the headset and microphone separately, not trough one 3.5 mm slot and not at the same time.
